# Group a list column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame, containing the following data:

```
| img  |  list_col1   |          list_col2          |
|------|--------------|-----------------------------|
| img1 | [str1]       | [[list1], [list2]]          |
| img1 | [str2, str3] | [[list3], [list4]]          |
| img2 | [str3]       | [[list5], [list6], [list7]] |
```

I want to group by col *img* and receive the following result:

```
| img  |     list_col1      |              list_col2               |
|------|--------------------|--------------------------------------|
| img1 | [str1, str2, str3] | [[list1], [list2], [list3], [list4]] |
| img2 | [str3]             | [[list5], [list6], [list7]]          |
```

I used this code and it is not working:

```
grouped_df = temp_df.groupby(['img'])[['list_col1', 'list_col2']].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) :

```
from itertools import chain
​
out = df.groupby("img", as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

    img           list_col1                             list_col2
0  img1  [str1, str2, str3]  [[list1], [list2], [list3], [list4]]
1  img2              [str3]           [[list5], [list6], [list7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sum` directly (no need for a lambda function) to aggregate your lists. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'img': 'img1', 'list_col1': ['str1'], 'list_col2': [[1, 2], [3, 4]] },
    {'img': 'img1', 'list_col1': ['str2', 'str3'], 'list_col2': [[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]},
    {'img': 'img2', 'list_col1': ['str3'], 'list_col2': [[10], [11,12], [13,14,15]]}
])
out = df.groupby('img', as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
    img           list_col1                            list_col2
0  img1  [str1, str2, str3]  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
1  img2              [str3]       [[10], [11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so a straightforward answer. Needed to create separate aggregation funcs and apparently I can use sum to join lists. I would appreciate other solutions too.

```
# Define the aggregation functions
agg_functions = {
    'list_col1': lambda x: sum(x, []),
    'list_col2': lambda x: sum(x, [])
}

# Group the DataFrame by 'img' and apply the aggregation functions
df_transformed = df.groupby('img').agg(agg_functions).reset_index()

# Rename the columns to match the desired output
df_transformed.columns = ['img', 'list_col1', 'list_col2']

# Print the result
print(df_transformed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'img': ['img1', 'img1', 'img2'],
    'list_col1': [['str1'], ['str2', 'str3'], ['str3']],
    'list_col2': [['[list1], [list2]'], ['[list3], [list4]'], ['[list5], [list6], [list7]']]
}

m_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = m_df.groupby('img')['list_col1'].apply(list)
df1 = m_df.groupby('img')['list_col1'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2 = m_df.groupby('img')['list_col2'].apply(list).reset_index()

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='img')
df3["list_col1"] = df3.apply(lambda row : [num for sublist in row["list_col1"] for num in sublist], axis=1)
df3["list_col2"] = df3.apply(lambda row : [num for sublist in row["list_col2"] for num in sublist], axis=1)
```

**output**

```
    img           list_col1                             list_col2
0  img1  [str1, str2, str3]  [[list1], [list2], [list3], [list4]]
1  img2              [str3]           [[list5], [list6], [list7]]
```